# ASP.NET: SHA1 + Salt Password Hashing on Multiple Servers

Tags: c#, asp.net, encryption, sha1, password-hash

So, I am the approach David Hayden posted on his blog (http://davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2004/02/16/157.aspx) to create a salt and hash the user's password by taking the user's raw password and the generated salt and using SHA1 to hash the value.

I then store the salt and the hashed password in the database.

The website is currently load balanced, so I was wondering if resulting hash value would be the same for both servers.

Here is the snippet of code posted on David Hayden's blog:

```
private static string CreateSalt(int size)
  {
   //Generate a cryptographic random number.
   RNGCryptoServiceProvider rng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
   byte[] buff = new byte[size];
   rng.GetBytes(buff);

   // Return a Base64 string representation of the random number.
   return Convert.ToBase64String(buff);
  }

private static string CreatePasswordHash(string pwd, string salt)
  {
   string saltAndPwd = String.Concat(pwd, salt);
   string hashedPwd =
    FormsAuthentication.HashPasswordForStoringInConfigFile(
    saltAndPwd, "sha1");

   return hashedPwd;
  }
```

The reason I ask is that this code uses the code snippet:

```
FormsAuthentication.HashPasswordForStoringInConfigFile(
        saltAndPwd, "sha1");
```

Comment: Don't limit your salt to ASCII characters.

Comment: I like `Rfc2898DeriveBytes` with a per-user and a per-application salt.

Comment: @Code: ASCII characters are more likely to be found in rainbow tables.

Comment: Since you typically use a salt wit at list 64 bits of entropy it doesn't matter.

Comment: @SLaks: I just use a GUID, ToString() it, and SHA512. Try to rainbow table that :p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the key question your asking here is if the SHA1 algorithm is the same whatever server it is running on.  In which case the answer is yes.

Presumably you store your generated salt somewhere that all the servers can access it, along with the password hash?  So the method used to generate the salt doesn't need to be consistent across servers.

Answer (score 1):

This method will only use the parameters passed into it.
Don't worry about it; it will work.

Answer (score 0):

"To address this issue, the validationKey and decryptionKey values must be identical on all computers in the Web farm."
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647070.aspx#pagexplained0002_webfarmscenarios

Comment: yes different issue, the hash is the same on all servers since it uses the same algorithm, nothing to do with keys

Comment: Thanks! That was my concern initially, but glad to know that it doesn't matter.